# Why does ContentFlow fail in Firefox, IE when I try to combine it with jFlickrFeed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, flickr

Here's a working example of ContentFlow using three static images hard-coded in HTML: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/WB-Browser/example.html

It works in FF, IE8, Safari, and Chrome.

I tweaked this page a little to make it pull in a Flickr feed using jFlickrFeed. It works great in webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome), but fails in FF or IE. See below for the specific errors.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/WB-Browser/example-jflickrfeed.html

Here is the document.ready handler I'm using:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.flow').jflickrfeed({
            limit: 3,
            qstrings: {
                id: '60829137@N05'
            },
            itemTemplate: 
                '<img class="item" src="{{image_b}}" />' 
        }, function() {
            var wbFlow = new ContentFlow('wbContainer', { 
                circularFlow:   false,
                startItem:      0
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

**UPDATE**: Just wanted to add some info in case it might help anyone help me. Firefox and IE both seem to choke on line 1652 of contentflow_src.js. Firefox throws the following error when I attempt to move the slider: "this.items[index] is undefined"

IE says of line 1652: "'this.items[...].label' is null or not an object"

Additionally, IE complains about line 1119: "'this._activeItem.index' is null or not an object"

But, again, Chrome and Safari don't throw any errors and the scripts work flawlessly in those two browsers.

Comment: Okay, found a problem: I put "href" instead of "src" within the <img> tag in the itemTemplate. After fixing that, the script still does not work. It creates the slider, but the images never become visible. Trying to manipulate the slider produces tons of "this.items[O] is undefined" errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this for a while now and I hit on a solution.

As shown above, I was creating a new CF object in the jFlickrFeed callback, but that wasn't working.

Instead, I removed the CF  tag from the head of the document. And instead of making a new CF object in the callback, I dynamically load the entire ContentFlow script:

```
function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'contentflow.js');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
});
```

See how it works here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/WB-Browser/example2-jflickrfeed.html

There are problems to this approach, though. For one thing ContentFlow does a lot of its own dynamic loading (addons, stylesheets, etc). Using my method above, some those functions break (especially in Internet Explorer), requiring alterations to the contentflow.js script.

If you're interested in seeing how I altered the script, take a look here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27409695/WB-Browser/contentflow_src_modified.js